# define table of columns based on condition using R

Tags: r

I have data which is stored in a dataframe as

```
CST   M     QS
501 1204315 1
501 1204324 1
501 6041541 2
501 7508226 1
501 7509677 1
501 7514622 1
503 7511601 2
507 6961200 2
507 7514100 2
507 7522029 1
509 7512374 1
509 7516799 2
511 419110  0.5
511 6000832 5
511 6960800 3.33
511 7010000 2
511 7508229 2.5
511 7508307 2
511 7515126 2
```

Now, i would like to change this data based on CST different M has to be stored in different columns. These columns should be dynamic such that CST can have only 1 M or it can be 10 or 20 or infinite that many columns has to be generated with M1, M2, M3 and so on. QS has to be displayed with sum of the values based on sum(M)

Sample output is as below

```
cst M1      M2      M3      M4      M5      M6      M7      Total
501 1204315 1204324 6041541 7508226 7509677 7514622         7
503 7511601                                                 2
507 6961200 7514100 7522029                                 5
509 7512374 7516799                                         3
511 419110  6000832 6960800 7010000 7508229 7508307 7515126 17.33
```

I have used transpose() where it just converts rows to columns.But this will not resolve to the expected output which i want.

I have tried using data.table function as `dt[,sum(QS),by="CST"]` but am not able to display M along with it in different columns.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'CST', we get the sequence of rows (`1:.N`) and `sum` of "QS", assign (`:=`) the output to create two columns ("N", "Total").  Then, we use `dcast` to convert from `long` to `wide` format.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, c("N", "Total") := list(paste0("M", 1:.N), sum(QS)), CST]
dcast(df1, CST+Total~N, value.var='M')
#   CST Total      M1      M2      M3      M4      M5      M6      M7
#1: 501  7.00 1204315 1204324 6041541 7508226 7509677 7514622      NA
#2: 503  2.00 7511601      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
#3: 507  5.00 6961200 7514100 7522029      NA      NA      NA      NA
#4: 509  3.00 7512374 7516799      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
#5: 511 17.33  419110 6000832 6960800 7010000 7508229 7508307 7515126
```

---

Or we use the same methodology with `dplyr/tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(CST) %>%
  mutate(Total=sum(QS), N=row_number()) %>% 
  select(-QS) %>%
  spread(N, M)
```

#### Update

If we need the columns in the order, we can convert the "N" to `factor` with `levels` specified

```
 setDT(df2)[,  c("N", "Total") := list(paste0("M", 1:.N), sum(QS)), CST]
 df2[, N:= factor(N, levels=unique(N))]
 dcast(df2, CST+Total~N, value.var="M")
```

#### data

```
 df2 <- structure(list(CST = c(501L, 501L, 501L, 501L, 501L, 
 501L, 501L, 
 501L, 501L, 501L, 501L, 501L, 503L, 507L, 507L, 507L, 509L, 509L, 
 511L, 511L, 511L, 511L, 511L, 511L, 511L), M = c(1204315L, 1204324L, 
 6041541L, 7508226L, 7509677L, 7434399L, 7843392L, 7834393L, 8343999L, 
 3439242L, 3434323L, 7514622L, 7511601L, 6961200L, 7514100L, 7522029L, 
 7512374L, 7516799L, 419110L, 6000832L, 6960800L, 7010000L, 7508229L, 
 7508307L, 7515126L), QS = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0.5, 5, 3.33, 2, 2.5, 2, 2)),
 .Names = c("CST", 
 "M", "QS"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -25L))
```

Comment: There was a comment, which I didn't see.

Comment: thanks for your response it is displaying output in console as you have shown but when i check the dataframe it is not stored as displayed in console.

Comment: @Pallavi I think you need to assign it to a new object i.e. `res <- dcast(..`

Comment: if there are more than 10 columns then the order of columns is getting changes as M1, M10, M11 .... M19, M2, M20, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8, M9 as such can we make it as M1, M2, M3...M9, M10, M11, and so on till the number of columns

Comment: using group_by is giving error as  "Error in rank(x, ties.method = "first", na.last = "keep") : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default"

Comment: @Pallavi Yes, change the column to `factor` and specify the levels to get in the same order

Comment: @Pallavi Updated the post with the order fixed.  Regarding the `group_by` (in `dplyr`?), I am not getting an error.